# Show object in input fields from http GET, Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have the id of a record that I'm sending with an HTTP GET call, so I can show that record in a form, edit it, then HTTP PUT to update.  I think my GET call to the API works ok, as I can see the correct object in the console Network Preview, and 200 status.  But it is not an array, so I can't figure out how to show this object in the HTML.
If I try to use an array variable and *ngFor..., I get this error...

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

If I use a regular variable of type any, there is no error, but no data binding in the HTML inputs.

Is there a way to change the service call to return an array, or another solution?  API Back end is .NET Core.

This is what the object coming in looks like...

```
{classTimeSubjectsID: 3, classTimeSubjectsName: "English", 
classTimeSubjectsType: "D",…}
classTimeSubjectsID: 3
classTimeSubjectsName: "English"
classTimeSubjectsStatus: "A"
classTimeSubjectsType: "D"
```

Here is HTML...

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(updateSubject)" #updateSubject="ngForm">
   <div *ngFor="let sub of editSubject" class="col-sm-5 form-group">
      <label for="name">Subject Name</label>      
 <input type="text" id="ClassTimeSubjectsName" class="form-control" 
      name="ClassTimeSubjectsName" value="classTimeSubjectsName" 
#classTimeSubjectsName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="sub.classTimeSubjectsName" [(ngModel)]="ClassTimeSubjectsName">
```

Here is the service...

```
 public getOneSubject(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.accessPointUrl}/${id}`, {headers: 
this.headers});}
```

Here is the component.ts...

```
export class AdminSubjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public editSubject: Array<any>;
// also tried....
public editSubject: any;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
    private dataAdminService: DataAdminService) {
      const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      dataAdminService.getOneSubject(id).subscribe((importSubject: any) => 
this.editSubject = importSubject);
      console.log('edit sub ' + this.editSubject);
 }
```

Comment: use https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood. Why don't you just wrap it in an array? like:

```
this.editSubject = [ importSubject ]
```

If you're unsure wether importSubject is an array or not:

```
if (!Array.isArray(importSubject)){
    this.editSubject = [ importSubject];
} else {
    this.editSubject = importSubject;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, yes that is all I needed.  I thought since I declared editSubject as an array, that was enough.  I didn't think to define it in the service call too.

Answer (score 0):

i have created something like this before
Hope it helps

```
    <div class="container">
  <main class="col-12">
<h3 class="bd-title" id="content">Dirty Check Example</h3>
<br/>
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Id</label>
    <input   value="{{data.emp.id}}" type="text" formControlName="id" class="form-control"  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input   value="{{data.emp.name}}" type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control"  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Designation</label>
    <input   value="{{data.emp.designation}}" type="text" formControlName="designation" class="form-control"  />
</div>
<button [disabled]="!(editForm.valid ||!editForm['isDirty']())" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form> 
</main></div>
```

ts file

```
editForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeeComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private service: EmployeeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl({ disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      name: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(
          /^[A-Za-z]{1,16}([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})$/
        )
      ]),
      designation: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(
          /^[A-Za-z]{1,16}([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})$/
        )
      ])
    });
  }

 onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.editForm.value);
    this.service.updateEmployee(this.editForm.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editform-egqagp)

Comment: Thank you for this example.  I tried to apply it, but could not get it to work.  Maybe because I'm not using Reactive Forms.  I did get my code to work by establishing the variable as an array in the service call.